# Confused about certs in provisioning profiles - developer or distribution?

Tags: ios, app-store, code-signing, testflight

I inherited an old project from long before the days of automatic certs and signing, and I've never figured all of it out. My confusion for today is this:

I have two iOS certificates at Apple, iOS Distribution and iOS Development.

I have one AppID, which has the complete ID of the app in it.

I have two provisioning profiles, Adhoc and Distribution. **They are both signed with the same appid and iOS Distribution cert**.

Question: is that last part a problem? I don't really understand the difference between the two certs, if any.

If this is a problem, do I need a second appid as well, or can I simply change the cert to use the iOS Development cert and go?

Comment: To add to this: selecting Adhoc under Profile in Build Settings flips the Code Signing Identity to Distribution... but not "iOS Distribution", something called "iPhone Distribution". This does not appear in the list under Preferences->Accounts->View details. Where might Xcode be getting this, and why don't I see "iOS Distribution" in that same list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First, some general info about the certificates and provisioning profiles:**

A distribution provisioning profile is for submitting apps to the Appstore. It uses a distribution certificate. Apps that are built with a distribution provisioning profile can only be downloaded from AppStore.

An Adhoc provision profile also uses a distribution certificate but it is usually used for sending in-production versions of the app to multiple users for testing, or simply for doing in-house Adhoc distribution within a company. Apps that are built with an Adhoc provisioning profile can only run in devices whose UDIDs were added to the provisioning profile during the profile creation process.

**And the answer to your question:**

You don't need two appids. All of your builds will use the same appid. But you will need a separate developer certificate and a developer provisioning profile in order to run the app in your test devices during development. Changing the certificate of a distribution provisioning profile to a developer certificate isn't enough. But of course, when creating the developer provisioning profile, you need to add the UDIDs of your test devices just like you did when creating a Adhoc provision profile. Otherwise your builds won't work in your devices.

Comment: Ok, so then I think the problem has nothing to do with the certs or profiles - it appears I have them set up correctly.

Comment: Yes, you can use those two profiles for Adhoc and AppStore distribution. But you can't use any of them for development.

Comment: Ok, so then I think the problem is not related to the certs, but something local on my machine. Take a look at the note I added, does that clarify anything?

Comment: There's two sections in the list that pops up when selecting the code signing identity. The ones in the "Automatic" section will select the correct certificate automatically according to the type you have chosen. You can see the actual certificates from the app "Keychain Access" in OSX.

Comment: That's what I did, but that automatically selected some ancient cert, and when I pop it up to select what I think is the right one, there's nothing else listed there. Wait - I deleted all my old keys in Keychain Access and now I don't have anything for iOS Distribution in Accounts. I suspect this is the problem all along. Am I simply missing/have-bad keys?

Comment: Log out and log in again from XCode preferences. That should replace the keys you deleted from keychain access if you have them on your dev account

Comment: And we seem to have found the problem... doing so returned only the iOS Development to the Signing Identity. iOS Distribution, which is signing those certs, is not there. Where does this list come from, my local machine or the server? How to fix it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70806/discussion-between-cihan-t-and-maury-markowitz).

Comment: Many thanks to CT! It turned out the privatekey/cert for the development account had somehow disappeared. I was able to find it in my TimeCapsult (phew!). I deleted all my keys and certs in Keychain, re-imported the cert, and presto, everything's building. Wow.

Comment: I was about to write a summary of our chat, but you were faster :) Anyway, you're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

1. A provisioning is always attached to a certificate. If the certificate is invalid or invoked, the provisioning profile is invalidated too.
2. You can use same AppIds for your 2 certs (distribution & dev). You have just to configure the right one in your target Setting in XCode
3. Distribution provisioning is for distribute your application to iDevices via AppleStore or Ad-hoc or InHouse. Dev provisioning is just for devices that have been declared in that provision.

If your application is compiled with Distribution provisioning, then, all iDevice can install this application if they can access to the installation link. But, if the application is compiled with Dev provision, only devices that are registered with this provisioning can install application. You will have to select associated devices when you create new Dev provisioning profile.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Application compiled with Distribution provisioning profile will work only once submitted to the AppStore.  AdHoc will work only with the devices associated (you need to select devices when you create an AdHoc provisioning profile)

Comment: So, my Adhoc profile, signed with my Distribution cert, should be the way to go for TestFlight. Is that correct?

Comment: When TestFlight was independent from Apple (pre-iOS8) you had to used Adhoc profile. post-iOS8, you need a Distribution profile for TestFlight (including in iTunes connect) since your app can be distributed for external testers. More info available here : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/BetaTestingTheApp.html